# How can I get a number of different inputs from the user in while?

Tags: python

```
amount = int(input("The number of numbers you want to enter: "))
number1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "))
```

and
.
.
Now, after getting several different numbers, how do I put them in while?

Please guide me how to put some numbers received from the user and put it in while

Comment: you could use a list and add the numbers in it

Comment: But what have you tried? If you know that `while` exists, you must have tried something.

Comment: I can't understand what you think "put them in while" means. What exactly do you think should happen when the code runs? Why should a `while` loop have anything to with making that happen?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
# Ask the user for the number of numbers they want to enter
amount = int(input("The number of numbers you want to enter: "))

# Initialize an empty list to store the numbers
numbers = []

# Use a while loop to repeatedly ask for numbers until the desired amount is reached
while len(numbers) < amount:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    numbers.append(number)

# Print the list of numbers
print("You entered:", numbers)
```

Output:

```
The number of numbers you want to enter: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 7
You entered: [4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use a list:

```
amount = int(input("The number of numbers you want to enter: "))
list1 = []
i = 0
while i < amount:
    x = int(input("Next number: "))
    list1.append(x)
#do something
```